# Print a variable from a def python

Tags: python-3.x

My source code:

```
number = input("Give me a number: ")
num_2 = input("Give me the power: ")

def blabla(number, num_2) :
    numbera = 1
    for index in range(num_2):
        numbera = numbera * number
        return numbera

print(blabla())
```

keeps giving me an error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong; can someone please help?

Comment: "giving me an error" is not a problem or error description. Help at the same level would be "Adjust the code". Quote the error verbatim if possible.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number = int(input("Give me a number: "))
num_2 = int(input("Give me the power: "))

def blabla(number, num_2) :
    numbera = 1
    for index in range(num_2):
        numbera = numbera * number
        return numbera

print(blabla(number,num_2))
```

Not sure about what error you are getting just change the input dimension from str to int and it will process the requested logic you intend to carry out. And also you need to give proper argument index while requesting the function. Hope it clarifies your doubt.